# VBA Presentation.UpdateLinks method fails

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote a VBA code in Excel to open mutiple Excel files, then open and update links in corresponding Powerpoint files by running `ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks`

The PPT files are processed one by one.

**The problem:** there are always some PPT files(not specific ones) fail to update links. And the first PPT always gets updated successfully.

I have to run the code again, and without exception, this time all PPT files get updated.

I want to run the code just one time without having this issue. How can I solve it?

```
Dim PPT As Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPT.presentations.Open ("\someppt.pptm")

PPT.activepresentation.UpdateLinks
PPT.activepresentation.Save
PPT.activepresentation.Close
```

Comment: I/O operations (copy. paste, open, save) take more time than your code allows. There are many answers to this problem, just search on Wait, Sleep and DoEvents.

Comment: Hi, John. Thanks for your instructions. it really helps.